# How to get the terminal text those are overflowed during command execution?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Some commands have very large output texts in terminal. Sometimes some lines of texts goes out of the terminal during command execution. How to get that texts?

**Update:**
I mean the terminal that comes with Ubuntu(12.04).

Comment: In which terminal? And do you have some example code?

Comment: Terminal that comes with Ubuntu distribution. My one is Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When typing your command pipe it into "less" this allows you to scroll with the up/down arrows for example: `ls -l|less` Assuming you are talking about the standard bash terminal that is, which you probably are.

Comment: More of it, you can store the result in a text file like this: `ls -l > result.txt`.

Answer (score 4):

Also worth mentioning, you can use `tee` to send the output both to a file and to STDOUT:

```
$ ls -al 2>&1 | tee currDir.txt
```

This will list the files in the current directory, while also writing them to `currDir.txt`.  Note that the addition of `2>&1` will also allow this to capture anything sent to STDERR.

Answer (score 3):

Even though the pipe solution (with `more`, `less` and `tee`) would be cleaner, you can also have your terminal keep more lines of output in its window (so that you can scroll up to it).

In Ubuntu 12.04, the usual terminal is `gnome-terminal`. Open one, and get to the preferences window (*Edit > Preferences*). In the *Scrolling* tab, you'll see a *scrollback* value, which should be set at 512 lines by default. This value represents the number of lines the terminal will keep available for you to scroll up to. You can increase this value, or check the *Unlimited* box.

Also remember that the more lines you have your terminal keep, the more memory it takes to do so.

Answer (score 2):

1) You can use `more` or `less` with pipe

`L10@Leo10:~$ command | more` 
`L10@Leo10:~$ command | less`

or else

2) You can redirect the command output to another file using `>`

`L10@Leo10:~$ command > output`

after execution of above, you can use any text editors to view the `output` file.

Answer (score 2):

In "clean cases" (there's no term manipulation like what curses & do) you can also try if Shift-PgUp does anything. This will allow scrolling to some amount, usually a hundred lines or so. To cover more ground, use the methods others have pointed out.