# Print result of command by turn in terminal

Tags: command-line, printing, gnome-terminal

I have installed Ubuntu Server 17.10 and my problem is concluded that I cannot see full list of results of perfomed operations in terminal, because a scrolling is absent in server's terminal .

For example: I want to read whole list of results of command `netstat` in terminal but results of netstat command have a big list and they aren't placed in termial. To see first lines I should store the result in file and then open throught an editor.

How to output results of command step by step?

Comment: It is dublicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/510786/how-to-get-the-terminal-text-those-are-overflowed-during-command-execution

Answer (score 0):

Use following command `netstat > filename.txt`
It will store output of command in a .txt file. You can use any filename of your choice.

Similarly for any other command you can do as: `command > filename.txt`

Comment: Yes, I wrote above about this way, but I would like a behaviour as "man" command. Because I don't want to remove such files in various folders where they are created.